# SQLAlchemy substring is in string

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to query a database for records that have a string field inside an input search string.

Something like this:

```
User.query.filter(User.name in search_string)
```

Of course that does not work since it is not a valid SQLAlchemy statement.
This seems a simple problem but I really can't find the right column operator.

I tried the `in_` operator:

```
User.query.filter(User.name.in_(search_string)
```

But that of course is not working. What I need is a `is_substring` operator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In SQL it would be

```
SELECT * FROM user 
WHERE 'search string' LIKE CONCAT('%', name, '%')
```

SQLAlchemy [contains(other)](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.contains) produces the clause `LIKE '%<other>%'`

```
from sqlalchemy import literal

User.query.filter(literal(search_string).contains(User.name))
```

Comment: Awesome! If we want to compare ignoring cases, we may use: `from sqlalchemy import func` then
`User.query.filter(func.lower(literal(search_string)).contains(func.lower(User.name)))`

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

`User.query.filter(User.name.match(search_string))` or

`User.query.filter(User.name.contains(search_string))`

For use `in_` you have to use a list, like that:

```
search_string = ['ed', 'wendy', 'jack']

User.query.filter(User.name.in_(search_string))
```